# Measuring the phonon dispersion at edge of Brillouin Zone?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, neutrons

When it comes to measuring the phonon dispersion at the edge of a Brillouin zone, why are neutrons chosen and not photons?

Comment: Photon dispersion or phonon dispersion?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: Getting the required $k$ out of a photon is much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Phonons have energies in the range 10-100 meV. The wave vector of photons with energies close to the energies of phonons is very small compared to the typical size of a Brillouin zone. Therefore, photons can mostly probe zone-center phonons (e.g. Raman or IR spectroscopies). To probe zone-boundary phonons you need a large wave vector with an energy in the 10-100 meV scale, and this is what neutrons provide.

Comment: Hi @ProfM. If we take X-ray photons (which have a range of their wave length from $10^{-11}$ to $10^{-8}$), then the wave vector isn't much smaller than the typical size of a BZ, is it? Also: Why do zone-center phonons have a smaller energy than zone-boundary phonons?

Comment: Phonons have typical energies in the scale 10-100 meV, so even though X-rays may have a momentum that would allow them to explore further afield in the BZ, their energies (of the order of 100 eV) are way off, so are not useful to probe phonons.

Comment: As to your question of why zone-center phonons have a smaller energy than zone-boundary phonons, I don't think this is generally true. Many systems have zone-center (optical) phonons that are higher in energy than the corresponding zone-boundary phonons.